# Is often using int constants as parameters in communication between objects considered bad design?

Tags: design, object-oriented, message-passing

An app I'm working on is designed with MVC. The components often interacts with each other by passing int constants, which then have to be interpreted with `if` statements. I'm wondering if this is considered bad OO design. (Not specifically with MVC, but in general).

For example:

When the user clicks a specific button, the controller is told by the view `controller.somethingHappened(Controller.SOME_INT_VALUE);`

The view uses a constant int value in the controller as a message to tell what happened. The controller then has to have a lot of `if` statements to interpret the message from the view. E.g.:

```
public void somethingHappened(int message){
    if(message == AN_INT_VALUE) doSomething();
    if(message == ANOTHER_INT_VALUE) doSomeThingElse();
    if(message == A_DIFFERENT_INT_VALUE) doAnotherThing();
}
```

As a result the controller passes another int value into the model, as a message to do something. I.e. `model.doSomething(Model.SOME_INT_VALUE);`.

Which forces to model to also have a bunch of `if` statements:

```
public void doSomething(int message){
    if(message == AN_INT_VALUE) doSomething();
    if(message == ANOTHER_INT_VALUE) doSomeThingElse();
    if(message == A_DIFFERENT_INT_VALUE) doAnotherThing();
}
```

This results in both the controller and model having a lot of `if`s to interpret the messages the receive.

**Is this considered ugly and/or bad design?** Should I try to pass actual objects into methods, or make more specific method calls - instead of passing constants that have to be interpreted with a bunch of `if`s? **Or is this practice of using a lot of constants as messages considered reasonable?**

If it is considered bad design, how can I avoid this?

*(Please note: For the purpose of this question I'm also referring to enums)*.

Comment: Why those aren't enum? At least the information would be centralised

Comment: centralized doesnt mean or even imply synchronized.  enums can be far more of a headache than fixed numbers, but you have to do your system engineering to determine which is better

Comment: You could also have an array or a map of functions indexed by the message type, and only check to see if message type has a function to call.

Comment: In general, the best approach is to simply call the method on your controller directly. There's no point in encoding your operation to an int, pass the encoding to the controller, have the controller decode the int to an operation and then call the operation. Instead, simply call the operation directly and bypass all the int encode/decode stuff entirely. Even though you are using if's, what you really have is a BASS and those are always bad and 99% of the time there's a better/cleaner way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @dwelch using primitives such as int is wrong for two reasons. First, you are not performing math on them: this is the same reason why a telephone number should be encoded as a string, not an int. Second, you can use them out of context. If you define colors as ints, you could pass a color to a function requiring a shape. If you instead use an enum or class, that will no longer work (at least not in languages with first-class enums, i.e. not C/C++) which is a good thing.

Comment: Assuming there is only one right answer leads to common failures.  If there was only right answer you would never have had a choice.  Do your system engineering and the solution is part of the output.  If the two ends of the communication path are not always updated at the same time, not built with the same tools, language, etc, then a compiler generated dynamic shared solution will not work.  You need something static and defined outside the compiler to encourage success or at least avoid failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this considered ugly and/or bad design?

Yes.

> Should I [...] make more specific method calls - instead of passing constants that have to be interpreted with a bunch of ifs?

Yes, that's exactly what you should do. Unless there is some reason not to. Given that you've already thought of this much cleaner option yourself, I suspect that there might be, but it's not discernible from your question.

**Update:** If the called methods would have duplicate functionality, the object oriented solution is to put the functionality that *differs* into separate classes that all implement the same interface, and call that from within the function, using polymorphism instead of explicit branching.

So, using the information from the comment, you'd call

```
controller.applyStyle(new BoldStyle());
```

or

```
controller.applyStyle(new UnderlineStyle());
```

where `BoldStyle` and `UnderlineStyle` both are classes that implement a `Style` interface (or inherit from the same superclass) which contains one or more methods that do the *different* things and which are called by the `applyStyle()` method.

Comment: Here's why I used constants: I'm working on a word processor. There are three buttons: Bold, Italic and Underline. When the user presses one of them the view has to report the button press to the controller. This can be done by having the methods `setBold()`, `setItalic()` and `setUnderline()` in the controller which is fine. But in my situation all three of these methods do almost the same thing and only vary in one or two lines. In this case, having three different methods results in a lot of code duplication. So in a case like this should I pass constants instead of separate method calls?

Comment: @Prog: see update.

Comment: I see. So basically `applyStyle()` would have some logic, and at some point in it's code would call `style.execute()` (or similar) - which is the point in the code where the required logic varies from style to style (`style` being the `Style` object passed in as a parameter). Or maybe it would delegate the `Style` to the model and the model would use it for it's functionality. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Prog: yes, exactly. Ideally, you'd find that there are other places where you need style-related behaviour or data, and can collect all this in the Style classes.

Comment: Specifically with MVC, the view should have nothing to do with 'business logic' (applying bold and italic styles being business logic). So in this case, is the view instantiating a `BoldStyle` a problem? (Since applying styles on text is part of the functionality of the program and not GUI/view related in any way). Does it break the decoupling between the view and the functionality of the app? Or is it considered okay since although the view does instantiate a 'business-logic-related object', the actual functionality is encapsulated in that object and is not part of the view?

Comment: @Prog: good question, but artificially decoupling it wouldn't really achieve anything. It would make sense if the controller did more than just pass through the command. If you want to technically decouple it, you could use a map (MessageEnum -> CommandObject) and replace the if cascades with a lookup.

Comment: Sorry I don't entirely understand what your saying. Please let me present my question again: Is it 'considered okay' in OO, MVC terms to have the view pass the controller business-logic-related objects? On one hand - the view should have no connection to business logic, and in this case it 'touches' a business-logic-related object. On the other hand, while it does 'touch' this object (or maybe even instantiate it), it does not invoke any of it's methods or access it's state - only pass it around. What is your opinion on this? Is this considered okay or not?

Comment: @Prog: Yes, I would consider it OK, for pragmatic reasons. I don't think it's useful to be dogmatic about this. The point of decoupling in MVC is to improve maintainability by separating concerns. As long as the view's "touch" of the business logic is restricted to choosing which aspect of it to  call, this separation is achieved.

Comment: The main case I'd see for passing bare-bones object like ints and strings is if you're communicating between services. But if the M, V, and C are all in the same virtual machine, they can just call each other (as long as you're programming to interfaces and minding your dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

There are several choices here, in increasing order of preference (most preferable last):

- Bits (flags) in an integer. Can be confusing, but allows packing a lot of them into a single int. So

  DO_THIS = 1
  DO_THAT = 2
  DO_ANOTHER = 4
  DO_ZING = 5

  perform(DO_THIS | DO_THAT)

  if (command && DO_THIS{ doThis(); }
  ...etc
- Integer commands

  DO_THIS = 1
  DO_THAT = 2
  DO_ANOTHER = 3

  perform(DO_THIS, DO_THAT)

  for (command in commands):
      if (command == DO_THIS) { doThis(); }
- I favor strings over ints, just because they're more readable

  DO_THIS = "this"
  DO_THAT = "that"
  ...
- "Typesafe" constants (in case you don't have enums around)

  DO_THIS = new Object();
  DO_THAT = new Object();

  perform(DO_THIS, DO_THAT);

  for (command in commands)
     if (command == DO_THIS) { doThis(); }
- Enum is a formalization of "Typesafe constants" so use that if you have them

...

Generally, though, these schemes are useful when the calls have to be serialized & transmitted between processes. If you're just making calls from one section of code into another, you can just identify what you want done with the function names. Writing some sort of "router" function that makes a call to lower-level function replicates what the language does for you, so you might think harder about whether you need that.

...

That is, I try to keep it so that 90% of my code looks like it came straight out of "Learn Java in 30 days" (or Python, or whatever). That is, the code should just use the language in a really basic way almost all the time. There should be a pretty good reason why you can't just do it the basic way before you move to a broader generalization.

Comment: The argument _for_ using objects instead of direct function calls is one can decouple separate areas of the code and pass events instead. That means that e.g. the view does not need intimate knowledge of the controller (asker did mention MVC). An event could have a topic that is a string or enum describing what caused the event, which is strongly typed and meaningful.

Comment: @JohnGaughan Is the Command pattern an example of what you describe?

Comment: Command is a little different. It's a little hard bending this example to suit it. Essentially, you'd have to instantiate a `SetStyle` object that had a single `run()` method, and have the target of the style as an attribute. Then the MVC code would just call `setStyle.run()` to get the job done. But in this case, that's going the LONG way around. Command is really powerful, but I mainly use it in asynchronous processing, like shoving tasks into a work queue.